# disable left or right arrow at the last item

Tags: javascript, html, css

Just made a simple div slider with navigation arrows. The div slider works just fine, except, I want some sort of *CSS styling* to be applied to the **arrows**.

That is, when a user clicks the *left or right arrow*, up to the last item, apply CSS styling telling the user they've reached the end of the slider.

```js
let buttonLeft = document.getElementById('slide_left')
let buttonRight = document.getElementById('slide_right')

let container = document.getElementById('slider')

buttonLeft.addEventListener('click', function() {
  container.scrollLeft -= 90
})

buttonRight.addEventListener('click', function() {
  container.scrollLeft += 90
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #555;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
}

div#slide_wrapper {
  width: 440px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: fit-content;
}

div#slider {
  width: 350px;
  display: flex;
  height: fit-content;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.thumbnail {
  min-width: 80px;
  min-height: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

div.thumbnail:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: darkturquoise;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: goldenrod;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: powderblue;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: firebrick;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(6) {
  background-color: sienna;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(7) {
  background-color: bisque;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(8) {
  background-color: navy;
}

div#slide_wrapper>button {
  height: fit-content;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 800;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

div#slide_wrapper>button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="slide_wrapper">
  <button id="slide_left" class="slide_arrow">&#10094;</button>
  <div id="slider">
    <div class="thumbnail active">1</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">2</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">3</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">4</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">5</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">6</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">7</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">8</div>
  </div>
  <button id="slide_right" class="slide_arrow">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check to see if you need to disable each button based on the position of the scroll. Then if there is a need to disable a button, add the `disabled` class to the button, otherwise remove it.

Future enhancements.

1. Remove the hardcoded `360` value for the scroll end. This should be calculated from the size of the carousel items and the width of the viewport.
2. Allow more than one carousel to work with the same code. This could be achieved by using a javascript `class` that would hold the elements inside an object, separate from other carousels.

See the demo:

```js
let buttonLeft = document.getElementById('slide_left')
let buttonRight = document.getElementById('slide_right')

let container = document.getElementById('slider')


let checkScroll = function() {
  if (container.scrollLeft <= 0)
    buttonLeft.classList.add("disabled");
  else
    buttonLeft.classList.remove("disabled");

  if (container.scrollLeft >= 360)
    buttonRight.classList.add("disabled");
  else
    buttonRight.classList.remove("disabled");
}

checkScroll();

buttonLeft.addEventListener('click', function() {
  container.scrollLeft -= 90;

  checkScroll();
})

buttonRight.addEventListener('click', function() {
  container.scrollLeft += 90;
  checkScroll();
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #555;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
}

div#slide_wrapper {
  width: 440px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: fit-content;
}

div#slider {
  width: 350px;
  display: flex;
  height: fit-content;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.thumbnail {
  min-width: 80px;
  min-height: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

div.thumbnail:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: darkturquoise;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: goldenrod;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: powderblue;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: firebrick;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(6) {
  background-color: sienna;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(7) {
  background-color: bisque;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(8) {
  background-color: navy;
}

div#slide_wrapper>button {
  height: fit-content;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 800;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

div#slide_wrapper>button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slide_arrow.disabled {
  opacity: 0.2;
  cursor: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="slide_wrapper">
  <button id="slide_left" class="slide_arrow">&#10094;</button>
  <div id="slider">
    <div class="thumbnail active">1</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">2</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">3</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">4</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">5</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">6</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">7</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">8</div>
  </div>
  <button id="slide_right" class="slide_arrow">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Also for the future enhancements, would you help me upgrade the JavaScript, that is, against the hardcoded 360 scroll width. Just in case I may need to implement your code for a wide variety of sliders like this - with varying scroll widths.

Comment: Please ask another question and I will answer it there.

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution to this is to actually create a css class that defines the style of arrows when there are no more items and then just add/remove class based on current index of items